# Laravel Notifications Mark One Notification as Read

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-notification

I'm new to laravel notification
I want when to click on the notification the link takes me to the invoice and the notification should be marked as read
I don't know how to mark one notification as read.
I know that I should take the notification id to mark the specific notification as read but I don't know how to is it in a function.

[image]

blade :

```
   <div id="unreadNotifications">
                            @foreach (auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                            
                                <div class="main-notification-list Notification-scroll mark-as-read"  >
                                    <a class="d-flex p-3 border-bottom"
                                        href="{{ url('InvoicesDetails') }}/{{ $notification->data['id'] }}"  data-id="{{$notification->id}}" >
                                    
                                            <div class="notifyimg ">
                                                <i class="la la-file-alt text-pink text-center"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ml-3">
                                                <h5 class="notification-label mb-1">
                                                    {{ $notification->data['title'] }}
                                                    {{ $notification->data['user'] }}
                                                </h5>
                                                <div class="notification-subtext">{{ $notification->created_at }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                      
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                        </div>
```

Controller:

```
    public function MarkAsRead_all (Request $request)
    {

        $userUnreadNotification= auth()->user()->unreadNotifications;

        if($userUnreadNotification) {
            $userUnreadNotification->markAsRead();
            return back();
            
        }


    }
    

    

    public function unreadNotifications_count()

    {
        return auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->count();
    }

    public function unreadNotifications()

    {
        foreach (auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification){

return $notification->data['title'];

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a link in the blade

```
<a class="d-flex p-3 border-bottom" href="{{ url('ReadNotification') }}/{{ $notification->data['id'] }}"  data-id="{{$notification->id}}" >
```

Define a route for it

```
Route::get('ReadNotification/{id}','BlahBlahController@ReadNotification')->name('ReadNotification');
```

In Controller

```
public function ReadNotification($id)
{
  $userUnreadNotification = auth()->user()
                                  ->unreadNotifications
                                  ->where('id', $id)
                                  ->first();
    
  if($userUnreadNotification) {
    $userUnreadNotification->markAsRead();
  }
  return back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to send the id of the notification to your controller and make it as read it is the same as you did for all read